# Please, help to find source with examples by glib

Tags: c, glib

I've looked for a lot of sites but didn't find any examples by glib. I've seen only discription types and functions...
Perhaps do you know a good source?

PS. Thanks for your answers! =)

Comment: Examples that do what? glib is a fairly broad library.

Comment: https://lzone.de/examples/Glib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a tutorial, a little old but still applicable: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/tutorials/l-glib/

Here's a tutorial on the GObject part of GLib: http://www.arbingersys.com/2009/07/missing-gobject-tutorial-sample.html

Also check out the excellent book 'Foundations of GTK Development' by Andrew Krause, it has a chapter on GLib: http://www.gtkbook.com/

Comment: Thanks! =)
I looked for it! =)
I'm newb =(

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/a/90342) might help you with IBM code compilation

Answer (score 1):

The tests from the glib source code may be usefull!You should try those!